# Split dataframe with all values in one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got the following dataframe which is created dynamically but saves all the relevant values into one row:

**df**

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       1        |       2        |       3        |       4        |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| a1, b1, c1, d1 | a2, b2, c2, d2 | a3, b3, c3, d3 | a4, b4, c4, d4 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I need to have all a_i values in one row, all b's etc (the columns are defined and constant):

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+
| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
| b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 |
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Due to the circumstances that the number of different letters in **df** is changing from case to case I would need a dynamic solution which converts the **df** into the form above.

Comment: What are the values in the original DataFrame? Are they strings like "a1, b1, c1, d1"?

Comment: Each cell is a numpy.ndarray-object, consisting of the values separated by ','.

Comment: @TimSqua _Each cell is a numpy.ndarray-object, consisting of the values separated by ','._ Please provide the data in a clearer, more convenient format (see: [mcve]). As an aside, do you control the code which creates the DF in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

#### Update Pandas 1.3.0 explode accepts a list of column headers.

```
df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3   4
0  a1  a2  a3  a4
0  b1  b2  b3  b4
0  c1  c2  c3  c4
0  d1  d2  d3  d4
```

---

Given, df with this structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[np.array('a1 b1 c1 d1'.split(' '))],
                  2:[np.array('a2 b2 c2 d2'.split(' '))],
                  3:[np.array('a3 b3 c3 d3'.split(' '))],
                  4:[np.array('a4 b4 c4 d4'.split(' '))]})
```

Input dataframe:

```
                  1                 2                 3                 4
0  [a1, b1, c1, d1]  [a2, b2, c2, d2]  [a3, b3, c3, d3]  [a4, b4, c4, d4]
```

You can use pd.Series.explode:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3   4
0  a1  a2  a3  a4
0  b1  b2  b3  b4
0  c1  c2  c3  c4
0  d1  d2  d3  d4
```

Comment: This helped me extend the df as per my needs `df = pd.DataFrame({i: [np.array([x + str(i) for x in ['a','b','c','d']])] for i in range(1,5)})` Upvoted your answer. Knew the answer was explode but had to figure out a way to count each column. pd.Series was the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat similar to Scott Boston's answer, but much faster (`apply` is notoriously slow):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[0].tolist(), columns=df.columns)
#    1   2   3   4
#0  a1  b1  c1  d1
#1  a2  b2  c2  d2
#2  a3  b3  c3  d3
#3  a4  b4  c4  d4
```

Comment: The better answer in my opinion.

Comment: @ScottBoston If performance is not an issue, both answers are good.

Comment: This is so clever. You are taking the values from earlier df and creating a new df. What if the values were not an array but a string like `a1, b1, c1, d1`. Does this work as well? trying out but finding some challenges.

Comment: @JoeFerndz There are some other answers that assume strings. Have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the original answer:
If your columns only contain one long comma separated string in only one frame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ",".join(["a" + str(i) for i in range(4)]),
        ",".join(["b" + str(i) for i in range(4)]),
    ],      
).T
df.columns = list("ab")
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0].split(',')))
```

Additional content:
(this is based on other answers that already solved the question, but to have a clear idea about execution efficiency I though it helpful to test it and print it here... I was surprised myself and based on the results I will write the same functionality with way better performance in the future: credits to @DIZ and @Scott Boston)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({i: [np.array([x + str(i) for x in ['a','b','c','d']])] for i in range(1,5)})

def convert_using_explode(my_df):
    return my_df.apply(pd.Series.explode)

def convert_using_conversion_to_list(my_df):
    return pd.DataFrame(my_df.values[0].tolist(), columns=my_df.columns)

# this is what I would have most probably done before getting involved in this question
def convert_first_idx_to_series(my_df):
    another_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in my_df:
        another_df[col] = pd.Series(my_df.loc[0, col])
    return another_df
```

Now timing execution:

```
%time convert_using_explode(df)
Wall time: 2 ms
Out[10]: 
    1   2   3   4
0  a1  a2  a3  a4
0  b1  b2  b3  b4
0  c1  c2  c3  c4
0  d1  d2  d3  d4

%time convert_using_conversion_to_list(df)
Wall time: 966 µs
Out[11]: 
    1   2   3   4
0  a1  b1  c1  d1
1  a2  b2  c2  d2
2  a3  b3  c3  d3
3  a4  b4  c4  d4

%time convert_first_idx_to_series(df)
Wall time: 1.99 ms
Out[61]: 
    1   2   3   4
0  a1  a2  a3  a4
1  b1  b2  b3  b4
2  c1  c2  c3  c4
3  d1  d2  d3  d4
```

Note on how @DIZ version is about twice as faster as the remaining ones.

Comment: The dataframe elements are not strings but numpy arrays.

Comment: That is not clear in the question... and if that information can be extracted from the code representation that would be new to me. Downvoting simply because suggestions (here supported with text) might not provide the OP with a copy/paste solution for his problem is bad practice and discouraging.

Comment: It is customary on SO not to answer a question unless the question is clear.

Comment: The question wasn't that vague it could not get support in its original form... and besides the suggestions indicated in this answer are still valid.

Comment: The last answer that you provided `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))` does not solve the problem. have you tried it yourself?

Comment: You were right, that part was simply removed from the answer since the correct equivalent is already posted in another answer, namely the use of `pd.Series.explode`.

Comment: use this to create your dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({i: [np.array([x + str(i) for x in ['a','b','c','d']])] for i in range(1,5)})`

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic solution

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 6


df = pd.Series(
    {
        n: np.array([f"{chr(ord('a') + ci)}{n}" for ci in range(N)])
        for n in range(1, N + 1)
    }
).to_frame().T

pd.concat([df[i].explode() for i in range(1, N + 1)], axis=1)
```

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
0   a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
0   b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
0   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
0   d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6
0   e1  e2  e3  e4  e5  e6
0   f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6
```